# PHP Sessions' internal mechanics

Tags: php, session

From the manuals, I draw that when a php session var is set, it is written to a text file in the session_save_path folder.

I am just curious to find out if this happens as soon as the interpreter hits the line with the session variable or does it ( writing to the text file ) takes place when the PHP interpreter exits processing the file?

For example, if I were to set and update a session variable in two consecutive lines, (as in the example I gave below), does the PHP interpreter saves the files twice back to back?

In other words, which code snippets has the right commenting?

```
$_SESSION['my_variable']=1; // writes to the session text file
$_SESSION['my_variable']=2; // writes to the session text file again
die();                      //   

versus 

$_SESSION['my_variable']=1; // updates the session file contents in the memory
$_SESSION['my_variable']=2; // updates the session file contents in the memory
die();                      // writes to the session text file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data is written to file if:

- session_write_close() is called
- the script execution is finished

So provided that you don't do 1), your second assumption is correct.

Writing to the file every time a variable changes would be VERY expensive, because generally speaking accessing and writing to the disk is slow, hence why PHP won't do that. It should be noted however that caching systems such as memcache or redis *will* store changes as they happen, so it can be a good idea to rely on them when PHP sessions do not suffice in terms of reliability.

Answer (score 2):

The second one, the `$_SESSION[...] = ...` they just set the value inside your `$_SESSION` array and `die()` triggers this function:

> `session_write_close`
>
> (PHP 4 >= 4.0.4, PHP 5)
>
> session_write_close — Write session data and end session
>
> Report a bug  Description
>
> void session_write_close ( void ) End the current session and store
>   session data.
>
> **Session data is usually stored after your script terminated without
>   the need to call session_write_close()**, but as session data is locked
>   to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session
>   at any time. When using framesets together with sessions you will
>   experience the frames loading one by one due to this locking. You can
>   reduce the time needed to load all the frames by ending the session as
>   soon as all changes to session variables are done.

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Answer (score 2):

So, I tried to test this by doing the following.

`test_1.php`

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['my_variable']=1;
sleep(20);
exit;
```

and

`test_2.php`

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Here are the cases I tested:

- Executing `test_1.php` then quickly executing `test_2.php`.

**Result:** `test_2.php` froze until `test_1.php` finished sleeping.

- Executing `test_1.php`, removing the `PHPSESSID` cookie and THEN
  executing `test_2.php`.

**Result:** `test_2.php` executed right away with no freezing (`test_1.php` in the meantime was still sleeping) and printed an empty array.

**Novice conclusion:**

PHP opens a stream to the text file related to that session until the script has finished executing and then it "commits" the changes. (I'm not an experts, so my terms might not be accurate)

**Edit:** yet another useless test due to not consulting [the documentation](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

> but as session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes only one
>   script may operate on a session at any time

Comment: Yup, the default implementation of sessions in PHP blocks the file until the script execution is finished — the good thing though is that since each user has a different session file, this blocking behavior only manifests when the second request comes from the same client (ie same user), so it's generally not a huge problem in production. But yeah, regardless of the lock, changes are only written once at the end of the script (or after calling session_write_close() )

Answer (score -1):

Sessions will be written in cookies or whatever storage you choose only after flushing the setter page. ex:

> having pageA and pageB :
>
> setting in pageA :
>
> session["foo"] = "bar";
>
> **session["foo"] will be available to pageB only after**:
>
> leaving pageA to pageB
>   or
>   leaving pageA and refreshing pageB

that considered, the best definition IMHO is the second one.

Happy coding!

Comment: Why would the session be written in the cookie?

Comment: @Mahn "Whatever storage" means that you can store session in many ways, including database, text files or cookies. but not necessarily.

Comment: but this doesn't answer the main question. Not 'where' but 'when'.

Comment: Granted you can store the session data in multiple ways, but specifically storing it in cookies is a silly idea if you care about security.